# QuickBlox Android SDK OwnSurfaceView Issue

Tags: android, quickblox

Our team started building a video chat application utilizing the quickblox android SDK.  We have the requirements to resize the `OpponentView` to full screen while making the `OwnSurfaceView` smaller and overlaid on top.  Using this layout and method the quickblox iOS SDK is working as expected.

We are noticing that on most android devices we tested **(agnostic of OS level; however this was occurring on 5.0 and 4.4)**  the call would get connected and the `OwnSurfaceView` would not be displayed.  Shortly after this the video would crash.

We are seeing the following in the logs:

```
invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb7b00a07 passed to dlfree

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 10326 (Thread-1113)

PROFILE HAL: stopPreview(): E: 1417779352.559218326

config_MSG_ID_STOP_ACK: streamon_mask is not clear. Should not call PP_Release_HW

android::status_t android::QCameraHardwareInterface::setPreviewWindow(preview_stream_ops_t*):Received Setting NULL preview window

android::status_t android::QCameraHardwareInterface::setPreviewWindow(preview_stream_ops_t*): mPreviewWindow = 0x0x0, mStreamDisplay = 0x0xb82edc10

Setting NULL preview window

Destroying camera 1

virtual android::QCameraHardwareInterface::~QCameraHardwareInterface() First stop the polling threads before deleting instances

config_shutdown_pp Camera not in streaming mode. Returning.

vfe_ops_deinit: E

E/qcom_sensors_hal﹕ hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11

I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4

D/audio_hw_primary﹕ disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: audio-record

D/audio_hw_primary﹕ disable_snd_device: snd_device(16: handset-mic)

D/NuPlayerDriver﹕ reset(0xb82e4480)

D/NuPlayerDriver﹕ notifyResetComplete(0xb82e4480)

D/NuPlayerDriver﹕ reset(0xb8355c10)

D/NuPlayerDriver﹕ notifyResetComplete(0xb8355c10)

Process 10109 exited due to signal (11)

qcom_sensors_hal﹕ hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11
```

Answer (score 1):

The log represented by you related with error in 3-party lib. Obviously you were trying to manage Camera instance in a wrong way. 
in IOS version there are different instances for each opponent representation, however in Android one is used for both users. So you can't manage view for representing opponents separatly for each of them, but you can try manage video rendering on your view. via VideoRenderer.Callbacks instances.

In the nearest future we are planing to renew android webrtc module and add QBCustomVideoView for representing each user in separete view.

Moreover many other features will be added in new QuickBlox SDK version, for example the strongly dependency of QBClient instance from Activity class will be removed, code and logic will be reviewed, multi call feature will be added  and so on.